# Filtering an array of object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

The following program filters the given array of objects and returns an array with the objects that satisfy the condition "living:true". Instead of using "if (test(element.living))", the program only uses
"if (test(element))" and it is still working fine which is very confusing to me. So why is the program testing "if (test(element))" instead of "if (test(element.living))?

```js
var SCRIPTS = [
  {
    name: "Adlam",
    ranges: [[125184, 125259], [125264, 125274], [125278, 125280]],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 1987,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_alphabets#Adlam_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Caucasian Albanian",
    ranges: [[66864, 66916], [66927, 66928]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 420,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasian_Albanian_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Ahom",
    ranges: [[71424, 71450], [71453, 71468], [71472, 71488]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1250,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahom_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Arabic",
    ranges: [[1536, 1541], [1542, 1548],[1568, 1600]],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 400,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script"
  },
  {
    name: "Imperial Aramaic",
    ranges: [[67648, 67670], [67671, 67680]],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 800,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aramaic_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Armenian",
    ranges: [[1329, 1367], [1369, 1376], [1377, 1416],[64275, 64280]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 405,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Avestan",
    ranges: [[68352, 68406], [68409, 68416]],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 400,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avestan_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Balinese",
    ranges: [[6912, 6988], [6992, 7037]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1000,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balinese_script"
  },
  {
    name: "Bamum",
    ranges: [[42656, 42744], [92160, 92729]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1896,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamum_script"
  },
  {
    name: "Bassa Vah",
    ranges: [[92880, 92910], [92912, 92918]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1950,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bassa_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Batak",
    ranges: [[7104, 7156], [7164, 7168]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1300,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batak_alphabet"
  },
  {
    name: "Bengali",
    ranges: [[2432, 2436], [2437, 2445], [2447, 2449], [2451, 2473],[2492, 2501]],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1050,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_alphabet"
  }
  ]

function filter(array, test) {
 let passed = [];
 for (let element of array) {
  if (test(element)) {
 passed.push(element);
   }
  }
 return passed;
}
console.log(filter(SCRIPTS, function(element) {return element.living}));
```

Comment: There's no test function. As you can see, it is working as is.

Comment: It wouldn't be working for `if (test(element.living))` as that would end up being `element.living.living` which would be `undefined` and so the `if` would always fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works because within `filter`, `test` is this function (it receives it as the value of the `test` parameter):

```
function(element) {return element.living}
```

...which returns the `living` property of the element passed in.

That means

```
if (test(element)) {
    passed.push(element);
}
```

is effectively

```
if (element.living) {
    passed.push(element);
}
```

because all `test` does is return the value of the property.

Comment: So the program is smart enough to know that it should use the value of the property returned and use that in the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Do not recreate the `Array.prototype.filter` function. The `SCRIPTS` array has it built in. Your `test(element)` function is just a predicate that `filter` already accepts.

Just call:

```js
SCRIPTS.filter(element => element.living)
```

The outout of the program below:

```
Alive: Adlam, Arabic, Armenian, Balinese, Bamum, Batak, Bengali
Dead: Caucasian Albanian, Ahom, Imperial Aramaic, Avestan, Bassa Vah
```

```js
var SCRIPTS = getScripts();

console.log('Alive: ' + SCRIPTS.filter(e => e.living).map(e => e.name).join(', '));
console.log('Dead: '  + SCRIPTS.filter(e => !e.living).map(e => e.name).join(', '));

function getScripts() {
  return [{
    name: "Adlam",
    ranges: [
      [125184, 125259],
      [125264, 125274],
      [125278, 125280]
    ],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 1987,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fula_alphabets#Adlam_alphabet"
  }, {
    name: "Caucasian Albanian",
    ranges: [
      [66864, 66916],
      [66927, 66928]
    ],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 420,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caucasian_Albanian_alphabet"
  }, {
    name: "Ahom",
    ranges: [
      [71424, 71450],
      [71453, 71468],
      [71472, 71488]
    ],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1250,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahom_alphabet"
  }, {
    name: "Arabic",
    ranges: [
      [1536, 1541],
      [1542, 1548],
      [1568, 1600]
    ],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 400,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script"
  }, {
    name: "Imperial Aramaic",
    ranges: [
      [67648, 67670],
      [67671, 67680]
    ],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 800,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aramaic_alphabet"
  }, {
    name: "Armenian",
    ranges: [
      [1329, 1367],
      [1369, 1376],
      [1377, 1416],
      [64275, 64280]
    ],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 405,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenian_alphabet"
  }, {
    name: "Avestan",
    ranges: [
      [68352, 68406],
      [68409, 68416]
    ],
    direction: "rtl",
    year: 400,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avestan_alphabet"
  }, {
    name: "Balinese",
    ranges: [
      [6912, 6988],
      [6992, 7037]
    ],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1000,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balinese_script"
  }, {
    name: "Bamum",
    ranges: [
      [42656, 42744],
      [92160, 92729]
    ],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1896,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamum_script"
  }, {
    name: "Bassa Vah",
    ranges: [
      [92880, 92910],
      [92912, 92918]
    ],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1950,
    living: false,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bassa_alphabet"
  }, {
    name: "Batak",
    ranges: [
      [7104, 7156],
      [7164, 7168]
    ],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1300,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batak_alphabet"
  }, {
    name: "Bengali",
    ranges: [
      [2432, 2436],
      [2437, 2445],
      [2447, 2449],
      [2451, 2473],
      [2492, 2501]
    ],
    direction: "ltr",
    year: 1050,
    living: true,
    link: "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_alphabet"
  }];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I understand Mr. Polywhirl. I just wanted to understand how the program was working and did not want to create another program. Thanks for your input.